# How to express the following meaning?

Tags: logic

$\tan(\theta)$ is changing with $x_i,x_j,y_i$ and $y_j$ , how to express it in the above expression? should I use $\tan(\theta)_z$? thanks.

[image]

Comment: I mean tanθ is just changing, may be not the function of i and j, it is just defined by $x_i x_j y_i y_j$

Comment: Okay, that makes sense, but please describe your definition of $\theta$.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that the 1 and 2 subscripts are supposed to be $i$ and $j$ subscripts.

Both expressions you have written are fine, although with the first one you would need to describe elsewhere that $\tan\theta = \min\Big(\Big|\frac{y_i-y_j}{x_i-x_j}\Big|, \Big|\frac{x_i-x_j}{y_i-y_j}\Big|\Big)$.

Here is an even more clean description:

> Let $k_{ij}=\frac{y_i-y_j}{x_i-x_j}$. Then $\omega=\frac1{C_n^2}\sum\sum \text{sign}(k_{ij})\min(|k_{ij}|, |k_{ij}|^{-1})$, where the sum is over all $i<j$

Comment: thanks, but if i use tanθ in the formula, maybe other people will think tanθ is a fixed value. so... how to express it?

Comment: @Eric: First, that is simply not true; if you precisely describe how $\theta$ works then it will be understood. I sympathize with the idea that you want your formulas to be precise, but it is probably not in the best interest of the reader to write some ungodly thing like $\theta_{ij}^{xy}$ [which is still a massive abuse of notation], or worse $\theta(x_i,x_j,y_i,y_j)$. Second: in any case, you have done a perfectly good job of expressing it in the second expression, by eliminating the variable altogether.